# Changing a variable through a series of statements ... What is this technique called?

Tags: design-patterns, terminology, naming, variables

I'm looking at a function that that has several statements like this:

```
n = returnDifferentVersionOf(n);
```

I.e., the value of *the same* variable `n` changes progressively several times during the course of a subroutine -- rather than a newly named variable being assigned at each change.

What is the generic name of this technique (if there is one)?

---

A more full example might be (in Ruby):

```
# reuse same var
def cromulentize(str="")
   str = "wowza" if str.empty?
   str += " adios!"
   str = str * 3
   str.gsub!('a', 'X')
   str = str[0..-3]
   str.upcase
end
```

What is that technique called, as opposed to this one:

```
# uses diff vars
def cromulentize(str="")
   non_empty_str = str.empty? ? "wowza" : str
   adios_str = non_empty_str += " adios!"
   multiplied_str = adios_str * 3
   gsubbed_str = multiplied_str.gsub!('a', 'X')
   spliced_str = gsubbed_str[0..-3]
   upcased_str = spliced_str.upcase
end
```

(Note that in Ruby the value of a method's last expression is the return value.)

Comment: Why does it need a name at all?  I do this all the time, and if there is a name for it, I don't know it.

Comment: ... programming?

Comment: destructive updates?

Comment: I really don't get where this tendency to assign everything a programmer does to a 'pattern' suddenly came from

Comment: @James Maybe to save a lot of precious time and minimize misunderstandings in the communication between developers. Not to mention learning what the possible solutions are without having to reinvent them each time.

Comment: I'd call it using a Temp variable.  But such practice is highly suspicious and indicative of code smell.  See my answer.

Comment: @lortabac How exactly are you saving time if every single little thing gets assigned a named pattern and you have to go look it up in order to figure out how to communicate the idea to another developer?

Comment: @James Naming things is an essential part of communication. Instead of "I travelled by means of a four-wheeled motorized conveyance upon a flat hardened surface to my usual place of daily commerce," I can say "I drove to work." Similarly, "`str` accumulates a series of operations," is a better, more concise description than "the result of the first operation is assigned back to `str` so that it can be used in the next operation, the result of which is again assigned to `str` for the next operation, and so on until the sequence is finished."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases, `n` might be called an [*accumulator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_%28computing%29), or you might say that you're *accumulating* the result in `n`. That's especially true if `n` is used to gather the result of a number of similar calculations, like adding up a list:

```
n = 0;
n += foo.price;
n += bar.price;
n += baz.price;
n += qux.price;
print("The total is: %f", n);
```

*accumulator* is an old computing term for a variable (or in hardware, a register) that stores results for further use. You can see how the name applies when the operations are all the same, as above... the value in `n` piles up the way falling leaves *accumulate* on the ground. But I think you can still use the term *accumulator* even if the operations are not all the same, as in your example.

Comment: In neither of his examples were all of the operators adding something to `n`.  The first was replacing `n` with something entirely new, and the second was doing all sorts of things, some adding, some mutating, etc.  If there is a name for what the OP is referring to (again, I know of none) then what you're describing would just be a subset of that.

Comment: @Servy Read the question again -- the whole first section refers to `n` used in this capacity: "...the same variable n changes progressively..." In the next example `str` is used to accumulate the results, contrasted with the final example in which there isn't a single variable used as an accumulator but a series of variables each store a single intermediate result.

Comment: +1, but I would include that even in a CPU the use of an accumulator is not restricted to adding values. And it should be clear that this is just an analogy.

Comment: I'd say *accumulation* hits the concept pretty close to the bulls-eye, so I'm going to accept this as the answer. Although classically/historically the word seems to have been used when referring to an accumulator for numerical values, various languages today seem to use the concept more flexibly with respect to values of any type. (See [reduce/inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (as implemented in Ruby) a.k.a. [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).)

Comment: The CPU concept of accumulator may be the appropriate metaphor for this technique.  But I suggest to you that the number one cause of bugs in CPU language programs ( assembly ) programs, is the unintended, inadvertent reuse of the accumulator and as such, this is really an anti-technique.

Comment: @AndyzSmith I don't think the OP is working in assembly language, and the question is simply about what to call *intentional* reuse of a variable to hold results after each step in a sequence of operations. At the hardware level you're limited to just one or a few accumulators, which leads to the kind of bugs I think you're talking about. I'm not sure that danger applies at higher levels.

Comment: It does if you intentionally subvert the high level languages ability to manage complexity ( while still maintaining performance - compilers will optimize away all but the most convoluted of verbose variable declarations ) by using a single variable to temporarily hold multiple kinds of objects or multiple scalar variables represented in different fundamental units.

Comment: But that's not what's happening here. `str` always refers to a string.

Comment: Yeah, but what is contextual meaning of the string?  It would be easy to say that a function that got a person's name, upper cases it, and then took the **FIRST LETTER** for use as a hashing code would still be operating on a string.  But the intention of the use of the substring function is entirely unclear unless the resultant intermediate variable is called 'FirstLetterHashFromPersonLast'.  I don't think you should still call it str.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something here, the word you're looking for is one you already have:  variable.

> In mathematics, a variable is a value that may change within the scope of a given problem or set of operations.

With this technique:

```
# uses diff vars
def cromulentize(str="")
    non_empty_str = str.empty? ? "wowza" : str
    adios_str = non_empty_str += " adios!"
    multiplied_str = adios_str * 3
    gsubbed_str = multiplied_str.gsub!('a', 'X')
    spliced_str = gsubbed_str[0..-3]
    upcased_str = spliced_str.upcase
end
```

What you actually have there is a bunch of constants since their value is assigned once and never changed after that.

Comment: The point in adding variables every step of the way would be to improve readability for future maintainers. In many cases this is a good enough reason.

Comment: I removed the comment in my answer about whether or not the practice is a good idea because it's not relevant to the question of simply asking what to use for terminology.

Comment: Careful! Variables in mathematics are different concepts than in most (imperative) programming languages. For example, `str = str * 3` from the original example is an equation in Maths! It doesn't mean "mutate `str` by multiplying it by 3", which would make no sense in Maths. In many ways, its "variables" are closer to immutable variables in programming languages.

Comment: This answer actually has a pretty valid point re: my question. Variables by definition can (and in practice do) vary. Still, the style one uses when *employing* variables is a choice that affects program readability and clarity. I.e., if it's clear my method is just going to mess with the string `n`, then reusing `n` might be okay (an easier to type). But in some cases it would help future maintainers if I assigned a new named variable for each and every adjusted version of the original value.

Answer (score 0):

The closest name you could really give this is "'threading' (not in the concurrent programming sense) or 'compose' in an imperative language". This is exactly the sort of thing that (eg) Clojure solves with its -> macro.

http://blog.fogus.me/2009/09/04/understanding-the-clojure-macro/

It takes a series of functions that should be executed in a particular order and feeds the result of each function to the next function in the sequence. You could achieve the same effect by simply nesting function calls but that gets ugly fast.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: So this technique is actually 'threading', but using a global variable for each nested function to returns it's results into?

Comment: Yeah it's basically just using a placeholder variable instead of passing the function's return value directly to the next function. The two examples given in the question are equivalent, they just differ in how they deal with that intermediate variable. I don't think there's a single overall term for this micro-pattern the original question is asking about. The overall technique of calling a sequence of functions in order is what I was answering. The specific method of overwriting a single variable over and over again is called "destructive update" as @jk mentioned.

Comment: So, to your knowledge, have functional languages such as the one you mentioned been maligned repeatedly for having 'readability problems'?

Comment: Clojure's a variant of Lisp which is basically the poster child for functional languages that are maligned repeatedly for having readability problems ;)

Comment: May I suggest that functional languages's readability would benefit from properly documenting intermediate results and properly designing classes for accepting the process-defining intermediate products.

Answer (score -1):

ok, in response to downvotes on my reasoning, I submit.

**this is called using a Temp variable**

And

**it is bad**

---

I definitely like the second snippet better.  With new variable names I know **what is supposed to happening** instead of having to guess about the intention of the original coder.  This makes it a thousands times easier to refactor  code, to simply add two lines in between two existing lines, or to create a whole function for what was a simple assignment or manipulation by a accumulation or something.

Managing complexity is critical to success of any non trivial program, and this 'technique' of using the same variable name is not helping manage complexity.  In fact, it is making it worse, as the code reader has to deal with a  kind of multipurpose, polymorphic variable.

The only case I can see this being somewhat helpful is when

1. The scope of this variable is very short and adding verbose names would only complicate things more.  But beware, what seems simple and of short scope now, can easily be expanded over time, and programmers won't rename anything and eventually you end up with a mess.
2. Sometimes, when you know the expected output format of a variable at the end of a function, you MAY use that variable as it's own temporary holding area for some manipulations that are relatively incidental and the whole scope of the variable remains small.  But even this, SO, SO, SO many times, when trying to redesign and refactor code like this, I'd would have rather the original coder spent twice as many lines and twice as many variables, **just to show me exactly, in
   explaining to 6-year old level of detail, what is *supposed to be going on*.** Nonbelievers, flame on.

Comment: That's not the question about style. There is concrete question regarding name of specific technic. Whether it's good or bad technique it's a different discussion.

Comment: Negative.  If the variable is being manipulated by some 'magic number' or some canonical string manipulation, it is then almost universallly **a different thing**.

Comment: EG.  float Bank = 100.60; bank = Bank * EuroExchangeRate;  return Bank;

Comment: float BankInDollars = 95.5; Float BankInEuros = BankInDollars. * EuroExchangeRate;

Comment: I would actually say that the second example is using temp variables.  The variables are used to temporarily store intermediate results and are not relevant after that.

Comment: The situation is, they are relevant, when you try to redesign and refactor this code.  Using **poorly named, undocumented** Temps makes this much harder.

Comment: It's really a matter of perspective. If you think of `str` in the OP's first example as holding a number of different, unrelated values, then I can see the point here. But the values *are* related -- they're really subsequent "versions" of what is conceptually the same object (even though they're really different objects). IOW, the OP's first example is very much like: `str = "wowza" if str.empty?; str.concat(" adios!"); str.upcase!` etc. Does it really matter if `str` refers to one object that's modified over several operations or a sequence of objects that are conceptually the same thing?

Comment: Remember: they're called *variables* because their values can change over time.

Comment: Yes, variables can hold different things.  But the issue at hand is whether **a particular variable** once associated with holding a certain kind of information, should then be stretched out, to hold others **kinds** of information.  I would never say, hey don't use that variable in a for loop and name each iteration of the for loop index a different thing, because it is absolutely, deadly, crystal clear, that the transformations to the variable, the **variability** of the variable is to represent the number of iteration we have left.

Comment: It seems to me that if you are applying a transformation to something, then you are changing that thing.  If this transformation is so, so, so, bloody obviously of correct intention, then don't rename the variable.  But naming the new variable something else, I am getting a definitive clue as to the intention.  So, now if it turns out that str.indexOf.length.blahblah is not the right function To use to alter this, i can infer how to fix the bug by looking at the variable name.  And the one after that and the one after that.

Answer (score -2):

I would call it a mess.  None of those changes are related, either in cause or in effect.  Making all those checks and changes in one place in your code is pointless.  If this string is a significant property of a domain object, there should be meaningful, distinct methods which change it, each change being separate.  Unless you can provide some better evidence to show otherwise.

That is garbage code.

Edit: as I hope is clear from the discussion in the comments, this isn't a dig at mtoast.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it as long as it is clear why each line is changing n.

Comment: @Brandon The examples given are so disparate that they do not belong together.  If mtoast was simply choosing random examples to create a big enough set, fair enough, but that doesn't change the fact that this is not coherent code.  If mtoast really would group these kinds of statments together, that is not good practice.  Changes should be composable and easily reversible; that can't be the case when such disparate changes are lumped in one method.  Would you really create a single toUpper/checkBounds/trim/sort/defaultifnull method?  Contrast with Caleb's code, which is much more consistent.

Comment: @itsbruce You're giving the content of the statements too much weight. The very fact that the actual statements are nonsensical emphasizes the important difference between the two examples: a series of changes to a single variable vs. separate variables for each step. The actual steps don't mean anything -- it's a Ruby-ish [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).

Comment: @Caleb almost certainly, but I'm willing to take the rep hit just to make the point.  I know from long experience that the naive and inexperienced actually pay attention (even if unconsciously) to what are not intended to be significant parts of an example.  I used to know a CS lecturer who taught Pascal.  The procedures in his code examples always had the same names as the global variables they operated on.  90% of his students left with the impression that this was actually a requirement.

Comment: @itsbruce - I personally agree with you so I upvoted your question.